# How should I filter the results of a RavenDB Lucene search?

Tags: ravendb

Say I had a `User` class like this:

```
public class User
{
  public bool IsActive {get;set;}
  public string[] Tags{get;set;}
  public string Description {get;set;}
}
```

I would like to use RavenDB to search for the set of users that match following criteria:

- `IsActive` = *true*
- `Tags` contains both '*hello*' and '*world*'
- `Description` has the following phrase '*abject failure*'

I have researched the Lucene Query syntax, I have even got some stuff working, but it all feels dreadfully clunky with lots of combinatorial string-building to create a text-based lucene query string. I hesitate to put my code up here because it is quite smelly.

I think what I want to do it submit a Lucene `Search` for the Description and Tags and then filter it with a `Where` clause for the IsActive field, perhaps like this [Filter RavenDB Search Results](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12011519/776476). But I got lost.

I am using the latest official release (960) so all the groovy stuff that comes after this is not available to me yet. For example, [this solution](http://www.philliphaydon.com/2012/01/ravendb-searching-across-multiple-properties/) is verboten as 960 does not appear to support the `.As<T>()` extension.

**Question**

How do I construct the required Index and Query to perform a search that combines:

- a single constraint, eg `IsActive`
- a collection constraint, eg `Tags`
- a free-text constraint eg `Description`

to return a strongly typed list of `User` objects?

Thank you for any code examples or pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You query it like this:

```
var results = (from u in Session.Query<User>("YourUserIndex")
              where u.IsActive && u.Tags.Any(x=>x == "hello") && x.Tags.Any(x=>x=="world")
              select u)
              .Search(x=>x.Description, "abject failure")
              .ToList();
```

Where `YourUserIndex` looks like this:

```
from u in docs.Users
select new { u.IsActive, u.Tags, u.Description };
```

And you need to mark the Description field as analyzed.